# PHP Script cant see the result of a query in json format, no errors displayed

Tags: php, sql-server, json, database

I am trying to get the values of a table from a MSSQL Database hosted online, however, I cant get any data from it, I already looked several times in the code and cant find a error or some mis-type in the code.

I get both echos confirming connection and query were executed but then after that i should be able to see the json, but nothing is displayed, I am sure the query is correct because I use it in other places.

NOTES:

- I have the sqlsrv PHP extension

**The script:**

```
    <?php
error_reporting(1);

$serverName = "...";

/* Get UID and PWD from application-specific files.  */
$uid = '...';
$pwd = '...';
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,
                         "Database"=>"programaplo"
                         );

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
     echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

echo "Conexão: sucesso \n";

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM Obras";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

if( $stmt === false ) {
     echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

echo "Query: sucesso \n";

$json = array();

while($row = SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC($stmt)) {
    $json[] = $row;
}

/* Run the tabular results through json_encode() */
/* And ensure numbers don't get cast to trings */
echo json_encode($json);
/* Free statement and connection resources. */
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);

?>
```

Comment: Now we can all hack your database. Please remove your credentials from the post.

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: Then your query is not returning any data

Comment: It is, because if i add echo $row['NomeObra']; i get the results, just not the json.